# CloudFormation Template for API Gateway with Lambda Proxy and MethodResponse Headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

Here is a CloudFormation puzzle I think I cannot solve without your help. I'm trying to create a template for a REST API with CloudFormation (YAML). The API has a Lambda Proxy and has to have a MethodResponse as shown in the attached image.

[image: MethodResponse]

This is my template so far which produces the following error when building the stack:

> PostMethod: Value of property ResponseParameters must be an
>   object

```
      ApiGatewayAccount: 
        Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Account"
        Properties: 
            CloudWatchRoleArn: "some role"
      RestApi:
          Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
          Properties:
            Description: "some rest api"
            EndpointConfiguration:
              Types:
                - REGIONAL
            Name: RestApi

      SomeResource:
        Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
        Properties:
          ParentId: 
            Fn::GetAtt: 
              - "RestApi"
              - "RootResourceId"
          PathPart: part
          RestApiId: 
            Ref: "RestApi"

      SomeSubResource:
        Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
        Properties:
          ParentId: 
            Ref: "SomeResource"
          PathPart: count
          RestApiId: 
            Ref: "RestApi"

      SomeResponseModel:
        Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Model"
        Properties:
          ContentType: "text/html"
          Description: "Empty text/html response."
          Name: someresponse
          RestApiId: 
            !Ref RestApi
          Schema: {}

      PostMethod:
        Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
        Properties:
          HttpMethod: POST
          Integration:
            IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
            Type: AWS_PROXY
            Uri: 
              Fn::Join:
                - ""
                - - "arn:aws:apigateway:"
                  - "some-region"
                  - ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/"
                  - "some-arn-of-lambda-function"
          MethodResponses:
            -
              ResponseModels:
                Key: "application/x-www.form-urlencoded"
                Value: 
                  !Ref SomeResponse
              ResponseParameters:
                  - method.response.header.Content-Length: true
                  - method.response.header.Content-Type: true
                  - method.response.header.Connection: true
              StatusCode: 200
          OperationName: SomeName
          ResourceId:
            !Ref "SomeSubResource"
          RestApiId: 
            !Ref "RestApi"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-methodresponse.html#cfn-apigateway-method-methodresponse-responseparameters), it would seem that this should not be a ***list*** of key-value pairs, but instead just an object, where each entry is just another key/value.

I expect the following would work:

```
ResponseParameters:
  method.response.header.Content-Length: true
  method.response.header.Content-Type: true
  method.response.header.Connection: true
```

Comment: You're right - thanks! Still, when correcting this mistake the template seems to be not correct. I get now the following:

PostMethod: validation error detected: Value null at 'putMethodInput.authorizationType' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID ...

Comment: Take a look at the documentation.  It says that AuthorizationType cannot be null, and I don't see it in your `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` object. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html#cfn-apigateway-method-authorizationtype My guess is that you want it to be `AuthorizationType: "NONE"`

Comment: That's right. Another thing I had to change was the structure of the ResponseModels which works now with the following lines for both, status code 200 and 400:
`ResponseModels:
            "application/x-www.form-urlencoded": !Ref SomeResponse
          ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Content-Length: true
              method.response.header.Content-Type: true
              method.response.header.Connection: true
          StatusCode: 200`